# How to apply a patchfile such that it creates new files if needed?

Tags: diff, patch

I have a set of patch files, which include newly created files. Is there a way to tell `patch` to create those files or do I have to `touch` each one manually?

Comment: `patch` will create new files if they were created in the patch file.  Can you give more detail of what is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

patch will create new files if they were created in the patch file.

Comment: I should have accepted this answer years ago - At least this is how it should work, though I don't remember what seemingly went wrong...